# LTspice JFET Voltage Divider Bias Configuration

Tags: circuit-design, analog, bjt, ltspice, jfet

[image]

I want to simulate this circuit in LTspice program and find Idss,Vp and Idsq,Vdsq but cannot. How can i simulate transfer characteristic?

Comment: Select a Jfet part number then find its simulation model that probably has only Typical spec's. Insert the model in the LTspice simulation and it will show you how that Jfet works in your circuit only if its spec's are Typical. A real Jfet might not even work in your circuit unless its specs are Typical and not work if its specs are near minimum or near maximum.

Comment: Why can't you find those parameters? What are you doing that it doesn't work? If you need the IV curves, you need a `.DC` sweep, not an AC source.